# Error in compiling a sfml c++ code using protocol buffers

Tags: c++, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, linker-errors

I downloaded some example protobuff codes and sfml-networking but i cant compile the files and i dont what's wrong i definitly installed "libprotobuf-dev" and "protobuf-compiler" and also the code seem to run ok on other Pcs but when i use command make in terminal i get this error
this is the repository i cloned the example from :
https://github.com/An-Alone-Cow/schat
please help me i tried every thing

i also reinstalled all protobuff things several times and even installed  manually from github repository provided by google

this is the error massege i get

```
g++ main.o messages.pb.o -L/usr/SFML-2.5.1/lib/ -lprotobuf -lsfml-network -lsfml-system -o run
main.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited[abi:cxx11]()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedB5cxx11Ev]+0x7): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]'
messages.pb.o: In function `Message* google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<Message>(google::protobuf::Arena*)':
messages.pb.cc:(.text+0x177a): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAligned(unsigned long)'
messages.pb.cc:(.text+0x1799): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanup(unsigned long, void (*)(void*))'
messages.pb.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
messages.pb.cc:(.text+0x1855): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AddDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*)'
messages.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::Arena::AllocHook(std::type_info const*, unsigned long) const':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZNK6google8protobuf5Arena9AllocHookEPKSt9type_infom[_ZNK6google8protobuf5Arena9AllocHookEPKSt9type_infom]+0x3d): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Arena::OnArenaAllocation(std::type_info const*, unsigned long) const'
messages.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::CreateInstance(google::protobuf::Arena*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*)':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x22f): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAligned(unsigned long)'
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal14ArenaStringPtr14CreateInstanceEPNS0_5ArenaEPKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x24e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanup(unsigned long, void (*)(void*))'
messages.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::InitSCC(google::protobuf::internal::SCCInfoBase*)':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal7InitSCCEPNS1_11SCCInfoBaseE[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal7InitSCCEPNS1_11SCCInfoBaseE]+0x4d): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InitSCCImpl(google::protobuf::internal::SCCInfoBase*)'
messages.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdownDestroyMessage(void const*)':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal24OnShutdownDestroyMessageEPKv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal24OnShutdownDestroyMessageEPKv]+0x16): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::DestroyMessage(void const*)'
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal24OnShutdownDestroyMessageEPKv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal24OnShutdownDestroyMessageEPKv]+0x1e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdownRun(void (*)(void const*), void const*)'
messages.pb.o: In function `Message::GetMetadataStatic()':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN7Message17GetMetadataStaticEv[_ZN7Message17GetMetadataStaticEv]+0xc): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*)'
messages.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArenaBase<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet, google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena>::mutable_unknown_fields_slow()':
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv]+0x15e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAligned(unsigned long)'
messages.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal29InternalMetadataWithArenaBaseINS0_15UnknownFieldSetENS1_25InternalMetadataWithArenaEE27mutable_unknown_fields_slowEv]+0x17a): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::AllocateAlignedAndAddCleanup(unsigned long, void (*)(void*))'
messages.pb.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV7Message[_ZTV7Message]+0xb8): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsedLong() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 1


  [1]: https://github.com/An-Alone-Cow/schat
```

Comment: These are linker errors not compiler errors, tags edited.

Comment: I would guess (strictly a guess) some sort of version conflict between the protobuf compiler and the protobuf library. What versions of the protobuf compiler and library do you have installed?

Comment: no both are 3.0.0-9

Comment: I see that the download contains already pre-built versions of messages.pb.cc and messages.pb.h, so it's possible that you haven't built those files with your version of the protobuf compiler (in other words it still could be a version conflict). Try deleting (or renaming) those two files and run make again.

Comment: i compiled using the make command and in make file it does make .cc file again

Comment: and also I'm working on some similar projects and i have the same issue

Comment: do you see the protoc command executing? The makefile won't make the .cc file again unless the .proto file has a later date stamp than the .cc file (sorry if I'm telling you things you already know).

Comment: well i didn't know that :) but it still didn't help i even excuted the commands seperately but nothing changes

Comment: well your first guess was right ..
looks like my manual installation made a conflict and messed things up i had to manually uninstall everything to make it work